# как сделать в htaccess перенаправление аддресной строки любого вида на index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

движок сайта написан на js, задача в том что он долежн принимать запрос из адресной строки в таких вариантах, например

```
https://mysite.vip/mainpage
https://mysite.vip/about
https://mysite.vip/gallery
https://mysite.vip/gallery/interior
https://mysite.vip/gallery/experiments
https://mysite.vip/gallery/anypossiblegalleryname
https://mysite.vip/posts
https://mysite.vip/posts/1
https://mysite.vip/posts/2
https://mysite.vip/posts/3
https://mysite.vip/posts/anypossiblepostname
```

вот такой htacces имею сейчас для ссылок типа mysite.vip /about работает но когда после слеша добавляю еще параметры не работает, сыпятся ошибки js во всех возможных местах.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

использование node.js не подходит, нужно именно php!
еще желательно если количество параметров больше чем 2 перенаправлять на 404 не найдено, например в таком случае

```
https://mysite.vip/posts/3/2
```

должно выдать 404 страницу

или хотя бы просто нужно перенаправление всех возможных запросов без 404 страницы

видео демонстрация https://youtu.be/r_vJVU_bzLM

Comment: Ребята я решил данную проблему! Все потому что в корне сайта были библиотеки js когда я засунул их подальше в папку static/js/libs и заново прописал все пути все неожиданно для меня заработало, ура, ура, ура!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте решение отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess . В вашей схеме вы видимо пропустили запросы, которые выглядят как запросы папок. Такие запросы обычно разбираются уже средствами PHP.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, все решения перепробовал ни одно не сработало( те что и сработали то только для адреса mysite.vip/mainpage или  mysite.vip/posts но для mysite.vip/posts/1 не сработало хотя при переходе по ссылкам внутри index.php все работает но как только с адресной строки делаю обновление страницы по такой ссылке mysite.vip/posts/1 или mysite.vip/posts/2 или mysite.vip/posts/3 не корректно работает будто игнорируя второй параметр

Comment: я изменил вопрос добавил в конце ссылку на видео демонстрацию проблемы

Comment: У меня вот это работает

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php [L]

Переводит абсолютно все запросы на index.php

Comment: я целый день потратил и понял что для моей системы роутинга нужен node.js тогда оно работает, а для php не получается сделать. Спасибо что старался, я поставлю тебе плюсик

Comment: оказывается решение было другим) и мой htaccess все таки норм работал

Answer (score 0):

Все заработало я нашел в чем причина, файлы сайта хранились в корне сайта и что то пошло не так, а когда я создал внутри папку "static" не важно какое имя по сути, переместил в неё файлы и переписал все пути в коде, то все чудом заработало, вывод не храните файлы сайта а именно js скрипты вместе с index.php в директории